# POP a row from a PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql

What's an equivalent to the Redis [LPOP](https://redis.io/commands/lpop) command in PostgresSQL?

e.g. In the following table named `things` with a single column `thing` containing two rows, a and b:

```
thing
----
a
b
```

What's a correct command to atomically remove and return a row in the table? Using the above example, I'd expect it to return a single row ('a') and delete it as part of a transaction/lock.

Comment: `LPOP` of Redis has an unambiguous way to identify *"the first element of the list"*.  I assume you are aware that tables are ***sets***, not *lists* ? So there is no natural order. 'a' being placed first in your example does not make it the "first" row in the table. How do you intend to identify the first row? If you don't define it properly, concurrent transactions may or may not end up picking a different "first row" each ... If you don't care, then that's a definition we can also work with ...

Comment: Thanks - yeah good clarification.  I'm actually trying to emulate the set `SPOP` command, which is random, but used a list example for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a [data modifying common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
with deleted as (
  delete from things
  where thing = 'a'
  returning *
)
select *
from deleted;
```

Comment: Thanks - I edited the question to clarify that I'd expect a single row, and that I'd expect 'a' in the result, but wouldn't require that in the query.  To build upon your answer, I modified the clause to be `where thing = (select thing from thing limit 1)`, which works.  Is that atomic with multiple connections executing the same statement?

Comment: @DanTanner: yes, every SQL statement is executed atomically. Are you aware that there is no default "order" or rows? so your statement might return a random row, not the one with `'a'`

Comment: great - thanks.  and yup order doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : just curious, are there any difference with just `delete from things where thing = 'a' returning *;` ?

Comment: i love how i keep finding neat stuff i cant do in redshift